# Unable to backup/export/access an SMS conversation on Android

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sms, backup, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-z3

I am attempting to use "SMS Backup and Restore" to backup 2 particular SMS conversation threads from my phone. The SMS app I use is Textra. My problem is when I go to select the conversations (or export ALL conversations), it seems to NOT include the conversations I'm after in the list. In fact it appears to show every conversation (in descending datetime order, UNTIL this conversation, and then no more before that)

I don't know why this is the case. It almost appears like there's an issue with that conversation, and when it gets to that thread, it can't get beyond that. I understand that Texta supposedly inserts a copy of SMS's into the android's main SMS database. I'm not sure if the issue is with the backup program, or the data in the internal SMS database, or something Textra has done.

Two possibilities came to mind:

These 2 conversations are VERY large in size, thousands of messages, and a number of MMS/images/etc. Could this be the reason they're not available for exporting? Perhaps too large in size or something?

I switched to use an SD card at a certain point. Is it possible SMS Backup and Restore is only looking at SMS records that have been inserted into the SD card database and not the internal storage? (assuming that's how it works?) if that's the case is there a way I can have it look at internal? Is there a way to test this?

Note this is actually a very critical issue, involving a fragile, legal situation. I need to export/access these SMS's so I can access/format/print them out etc.

I have in the past been able to do this with SMS Backup and Restore without any problem.

I basically want to know how I can access and export these conversation threads. Does anyone have any suggestions? Would be extremely grateful and appreciative for any advice.

If there's another way to access the SMS data and get it onto my computer (raw data??) I would be willing to explore that if there's no other options.

I'm using Sony Xperia z3, with Android 4.4.4.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions on this?

Is there a way i can access the Textra data files directly - does anyone know where they are?

I am really stuck on this one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution to this issue. Rather than repeat what's already been written very clearly and concisely, I will just refer to the URL:

> http://blog.shvetsov.com/2013/02/access-android-app-data-without-root.html

This provides a way to get access to the SQLite database that Textra uses, and export it to a computer, without needing root access. I am sincerely grateful to the guy that posted this! Potentially saved me from serious legal consequences had I been unable to access this information on my phone.